# DevExpress Map Control not Loading - Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I am using the DevExpress XtraMap MapControl within a windows service with the intention of generating the maps, saving them as images and adding them to reports. I have this setup working well when using it through a WinForms project, but when I copy the same code to a Windows Service it fails to save the image. Code in the WinForms project:

```
 MapControl map;
        public void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a map control.
            map = new MapControl();

            // Create an image tiles layer and add it to the map.
            ImageTilesLayer tilesLayer = new ImageTilesLayer();
            tilesLayer.DataLoaded += Map_DataLoaded;
            map.Layers.Add(tilesLayer);

            BingMapDataProvider prov = new BingMapDataProvider();
            prov.BingKey = "MY_BING_KEY";
            tilesLayer.DataProvider = prov;

            map.ZoomLevel = 2;
            map.CenterPoint = new GeoPoint(38, -100);

            map.ResumeRender();
            this.Controls.Add(map);

        }

        private void Map_DataLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var loc = @"C:\0Temp\Map\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".png";
            map.ExportToImage(loc, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

This code when run in a Windows service fails to save the image. The only difference being, in the Windows Service, the following line is removed:

```
 this.Controls.Add(map);
```

When removing that line from the winforms project, it also fails to load/save. I can only assume that there is an event being triggered/monitored that adding this control to a form triggers that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, the Map Control is not intended to be used without showing it (or at least without creating it's handle). So when accessing to Bing Maps from Windows-service, I suggest you [to use the Bing Imagery API directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx).

p.s. Microsoft [Bing Maps Terms of Use](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html) do not allow to

> 3.2 (b) Copy, store, archive, or create a database of the Content ...